# find all string that starts with "Sanskar:214" and end with "<SP>" using re in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do something like

```
term3_pattern = re.compile(r'(Sanskar:214) * <SP>')
```

and then check like that

```
term3_pattern.match(i):
```

Can someone help me with the regex pattern?

Comment: Try `[Sanskar:214].*[<SP>]`

Comment: If you ask any question always provide examples to verify - this is especially important when you ask a regex question.

Answer (score 0):

*hey you can try this*

```
import re 
re.findall(r'Sanskar:214.*<SP>', s)  // s is  your string
```